# How to parse only 4 digit years

Tags: java, jodatime, date-parsing

I'm using Joda-Time to parse years like this:

```
private DateTime attemptParse(String pattern, String date) {
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(pattern).withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
        DateTime parsedDateTime = parser.parseLocalDateTime(date).toDateTime(WET);
        return parsedDateTime;
    }
```

I'm trying to parse multiple formats: `"yyyy-MM-dd", "yyyy-MMM-dd","yyyy MMM dd-dd","yyyy MMM", (etc), "yyyy"`. When one doesn't work, I try the next one.

And it works like a charm when the string is indeed only 4 digits (e.g: `"2016"`). The problem is that I sometimes receive things like this: `"201400"`. And Joda-Time matches this with `"yyyy"` pattern and returns a date with year `201400`.

I wanted to avoid the ugly if to check if `year > 9999`. Is there any way to do this using Joda-Time?

Comment: Why not just parse `substr(date, 0, 4)`?

Comment: @GriffeyDog Because I don't consider 201400 a valid date, so I have to throw an exception.

Comment: Doesn’t the length of the string tell you?

Answer (score 4):

To parse multiple formats, you can create lots of `DateTimeParser` instances and join all in one single formatter (instead of trying one after another).

This will require a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`, which will also be used to enforce a specific number of digits in the input (unfortunately, there's no way to enforce a specific number of digits like you want using just `DateTimeFormat.forPattern()`).

First you create lots of `org.joda.time.format.DateTimeParser` instances (one for each possible pattern):

```
// only yyyy
DateTimeParser p1 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // year with exactly 4 digits
    .appendYear(4, 4).toParser();
// yyyy-MM-dd
DateTimeParser p2 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // year with exactly 4 digits
    .appendYear(4, 4)
    // rest of the pattern
    .appendPattern("-MM-dd").toParser();
// yyyy MMM
DateTimeParser p3 = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // year with exactly 4 digits
    .appendYear(4, 4)
    // rest of the pattern
    .appendPattern(" MMM").toParser();
```

Then you create an array with all these patterns and create a `DateTimeFormatter` with it:

```
// create array with all the possible patterns
DateTimeParser[] possiblePatterns = new DateTimeParser[] { p1, p2, p3 };

DateTimeFormatter parser = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // append all the possible patterns
    .append(null, possiblePatterns)
    // use the locale you want (in case of month names and other locale sensitive data)
    .toFormatter().withLocale(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

I also used `Locale.ENGLISH` (as you're also using it in your question's code). This locale indicates that the month names will be in English (so `MMM` can parse values like `Jan` and `Sep`). With this, you can parse the inputs:

```
System.out.println(parser.parseLocalDateTime("2014")); // OK
System.out.println(parser.parseLocalDateTime("201400")); // exception
System.out.println(parser.parseLocalDateTime("2014-10-10")); // OK
System.out.println(parser.parseLocalDateTime("201400-10-10")); // exception
System.out.println(parser.parseLocalDateTime("2014 Jul")); // OK
System.out.println(parser.parseLocalDateTime("201400 Jul")); // exception
```

When the year is `2014`, the code works fine. When it's `201400`, it throws a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`, such as:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "201400" is malformed at "00"

`DateTimeFormatter` is immutable and thread-safe, so you don't need to create it every time your validation method is called. You can create it outside of the method (such as in a `static final` field).

This is better than creating one formatter everytime you perform a validation, and going to the next one when an exception occurs. The formatter created already does it internally, going to the next pattern until it finds one that works (or throwing the exception if all patterns fail).

---

## Java new Date/Time API

Joda-Time is in maintainance mode and is being replaced by the new APIs, so I don't recommend start a new project with it. Even in [joda's website](http://www.joda.org/joda-time) it says: **"Note that Joda-Time is considered to be a largely “finished” project. No major enhancements are planned. If using Java SE 8, please migrate to java.time (JSR-310)."**.

*If you can't (or don't want to) migrate from Joda-Time to the new API, you can ignore this section.*

If you're using **Java 8**, consider using the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/7605325).

If you're using **Java 6 or 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, you'll also need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the **package names** (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

This new API is much more strict than the previous ones, so the formatter only works with the exact number of digits (note that some classes are very similar to Joda-Time):

```
// 4 digits in year
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
fmt.parse("2014"); // OK
fmt.parse("201400"); // exception
fmt.parse("201"); // exception
```

This code works with `2014`, but with `201400` or `201` (or any other value without exactly 4 digits) it throws an exception:

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '201400' could not be parsed at index 0

**With this, your validation code could work with the array of strings.**

---

There's only one detail: when parsing to a date, Joda-Time sets default values when the input doesn't have some fields (like month becomes January, day becomes 1, hour/minute/second are set to zero, etc).

If you are just validating the input, then you don't need to return anything. Just check if the exception is thrown and you'll know if the input is valid or not.

If you just need the year value, though, you can use the [`Year` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Year.html):

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(Year.parse("2014", parser)); // ok
System.out.println(Year.parse("201400", parser)); // exception
```

If you want the year value as an `int`:

```
Year year = Year.parse("2014", parser);
int yearValue = year.getValue(); // 2014
```

---

But if you want to get a date object, you'll need to set the default values manually - the new API is very strict and don't set those values automatically. In this case, you must set the default values, by using a `DateTimeFormatterBuilder`.

I also parse it to a `LocalDateTime`, just as example:

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
    // string pattern
    .appendPattern("yyyy")
    // default month is January
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR, 1)
    // default day is 1
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1)
    // default hour is zero
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
    // default minute is zero
    .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
    // set locale
    .toFormatter(Locale.ENGLISH);
// create LocalDateTime
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("2014", fmt)); // 2014-01-01T00:00
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse("201400", fmt)); // exception
```

You can choose whatever values you want as the default for the fields, and use any of the [new available date types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/overview.html).

Comment: This is probably a better idea than my pre processing answer ;-)

Comment: Actually I don't want to change to DateTimeFormatterBuilder because I simplified the question. I'm trying to parse multiple formats: "yyyy-MM-dd", "yyyy-MMM-dd","yyyy MMM dd-dd","yyyy MMM", (etc), "yyyy".

And when that invalid date "201400" shows up it gets converted and I wanted Jodatime to throw an exception. If I were to switch to the DateTimeFormatterBuilder I would need to make every date pattern with it :/

Comment: @micdcar In this case, could you please edit your question, so I can update my answer accordingly?

Comment: @Hugo Thanks for your answer, it indeed solves the problem. However, since I have 20+ date formats to parse from, I really don't want to create this number of DateTimeFormatterBuilder objects. The code looks much cleaner with the array of Strings.

Comment: @micdcar If you don't want to create lots of builders, I'm afraid the only way is to check if year > 9999. But I still think that creating 20 builders is better than creating a new formatter everytime you call the method  -because the builders can be created just **once**, outside of the method (better in a `static` field, in a separate class, making the validation code clearer, IMO). But it's up to you to choose.

Comment: @micdcar Another alternative to use an array of Strings is to migrate to the new Date/Time API. I've updated the answer, just in case you decide to migrate.

Comment: I'm using such a code for setup DateTimeFormatter:

`DateTimeFormatter dtf = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendValue(ChronoField.YEAR, 4).toFormatter();`

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying is that Jodatime should somehow guess that it should parse "201400" as 2014. I don't think that's reasonably within the scope of that library. You should pre-process the data yourself, for example by using:

```
String normalizedDate = String.format("%4s", date).trim();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually I don't want to convert this date, I want to consider 201400 as an error.